# Reading JSON properties without structure/model

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

How can we extract arrays from server response JSON strings?

The JSON object is serialized as such:

```
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
        print(json)  // output below                      
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

and the resulting output is:

```
    ["locations": <__NSArrayM 0x280e23f90>(
    {
        lat = "123.111111";
        long = "1.111111";
    },
    {
        lat = "123.222222";
        long = "1.222222";
    },
    {
        lat = "123.333333";
        long = "1.333333";
    }
    ),
    "mobileNo": 55551234, 
    "clientID": 2123456789, 
    "date": 10082019, 
    "time": 1854]
```

How do we read the properties like **mobileNo** and **clientID** from the **json** variable, and more importantly, how do we place the **locations** array into an array or dictionary?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide us original json instead of printing result? Also, I will suggest use [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) - it's very easy to use, easier than working with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JSONDecoder and Decodable.

1. Create response structure.

```
struct Model: Decodable {

  struct Location: Decodable {
    var lat: String
    var long: String
  }

  var locations: [Location]
  var mobileNo: Int
  var clientId: Int
  var date: Int
  var time: Int

}
```

2. User JSONDecoder to decode

```
    do {
        if let response: Model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, for: data) {
            print(response)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What are the disadvantages of accessing the properties directly? And how could we do that, especially with arrays?

Comment: For me, using codable is easier than accessing properties directly. To access location array just parse it like this `[[String: Any]]`

Comment: So, for mobileNo it would be **let mobileNo = json["mobileNo"]** and the locations array would be **let locations = json["locations"] as [[String: Any]]** ?

Comment: for mobileNo it would be `let mobileNo = json["mobileNo"] as? Int`